# Chrome Autofill & Autocomplete Issue on Text Box

Tags: jquery, html, angular, google-chrome, autocomplete

Although the question might have asked several time on the internet, every time Chrome gets updated, the solution becomes obsolete.

I wanted to prevent Chrome from showing **Autocomplete** suggestions. So I used `autocomplete=off` tag to remove them. Then the Chromes **Autofill** suggestion popped up again from the **Autofill form** option in Chrome. I used `autocomplete=new-password` to eliminate them,

But then the **Autocomplete** suggestion popped up again.

Is it because of the new version of chrome that they are now identified as distinct functionalities?

How do I prevent both **Autocomplete** and **Autofill**?

Answer (score 1):

please try using this-

```html
 autocomplete="false"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for autofill suggestion on Chrome.

Comment: You can also try using jquery disableAutoFill plugin.

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Disable-Chrome-Autofill-Autocomplete-jQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use `autocomplete=none` and apply this to the form and input fields.
After this do not forget to hard reload your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put **autocomplete="off"** in the **form** tag. It worked for me.